# JetBrains DotTrace

Tags: asp.net, iis, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I have setup the dotTrace for the website hosted in IIS server. When JetBrains dotTrace starts, the IIS website running fine and the profile starts. After the completing profile, the IIS website is not loading and it seems locked by the dotTrace. The website cannot able to start from IIS server.

The website again starts running if JetBrains dotTrace starts running again. This seems some service related with IIS webserver is getting locked by the dotTrace.

Please have a look at the issue.

[image: IIS error: while restart the website from the IIS]

Comment: @DingPeng You are referring to the same issue

Comment: Sorry. Please refer to this link: https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/cannot-started-unless-world-wide-web-publishing-service-running/